# Prove that either$ P(A∩B)=0$ or else $P(A'∩B')=0$

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $E$ and $F$ be independent with $E = A∪B$, and $F = A∩B$. Prove that either
$P(A∩B)=0$ or else $P(A'∩B')=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are told that $E$ and $F$ are independent. By the definition of independence, we have 
$$\Pr(E\cap F)=\Pr(E)\Pr(F).\tag{1}$$

But $E\cap F)=(A\cup B)\cap (A\cap B)$. The intersection of $A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$ is $A\cap B$, that is, $F$. Thus from (1) we obtain
$$\Pr(F)=\Pr(E)\Pr(F).\tag{2}$$
Now there are two cases to consider.

If $\Pr(F)=0$, then Equation (2) holds, and we have $\Pr(F)=\Pr(A\cap B)=0$.

If $\Pr(F)\ne 0$, from (2), by cancelling $\Pr(F)$, we get $\Pr(E)=1$.

Thus $\Pr(E')=1-\Pr(E)=0$. But $E'=(A\cup B)'=A'\cap B'$. It follows that $\Pr(A'\cap B')=0$.

So we have shown that if (1) holds, then either $\Pr(A\cap B)=0$ or $\Pr(A'\cap B')=0$. That is what needed to be shown.

**Remark:** We cannot interpret the "or else" as exclusive or. For if $\Pr(A)=0$ and $\Pr(B)=1$. then $E$ and $F$ are independent but $\Pr(A\cap B)=0$ **and** $\Pr(A'\cap B')=0$.

Comment: Was away for a while. Have written out what I think of as very full detail.